# How to get org_id as part of access token using Auth0?

Tags: javascript, auth0, rules

- I am try to get get org_id While generating  using UserNamePassword authentication?
- I have added rule as below

> ```
> context.accessToken[namespace + 'org'] = context.organization;
> ```

- After generating access token I have decoded it and I couldn't find  org_id in json response

Answer (score 0):

Does `namespace` have a valid value e.g. `http://www.myexample.com/org_id`? If not it might be getting silently excluded

> By default, Auth0 always enforces namespacing; any custom claims with
> non-namespaced identifiers will be silently excluded from tokens and
> silently ignored in Actions and Rules.

https://auth0.com/docs/secure/tokens/json-web-tokens/create-namespaced-custom-claims

You can debug these rules quite easily by adding some debug statements to your rule e.g. `console.log(namespace + 'org')` and installing and running the `Real-time Webtask Logs` extension

Finally, here's a full Rule example for adding a custom claim to access token:

```
function addAttributes(user, context, callback) {
  const namespace = configuration.Namespace;
  context.accessToken[`${namespace}org_id`] = 'test';
  callback(null, user, context);
}
```

note: `configuration.Namespace` is a rule setting with a value of something like `http://www.myexample.com/`